# Using templates for a factory method on derived classes

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a base class of which there will be many derived classes. However it is pointers to the base class that are stored in containers in my program so it can iterate through and call virtual functions on them.

I have another class that adds base class pointers into this container, thus when derived classes are `new`ed (not *nude*) they must return or get stored as a base class pointer.

I was thinking about making a simple base class Factory method that does this for me, using templates:

```
    template<class T> //T is the derived class
    static T* Factory(){
       return static_cast<T*>(functionThatAddsBaseClassPointerToContainer(new T));
    }
```

I see two main pros/cons:

Advantage: Don't need to override this for every derived class

Disadvantage: Could be used incorrectly by passing as `T` a class type that is not derived from my base.

Is there a way to ensure that `T` is derived inside this function `Factory`? Or can I expect the compiler to catch instances where `T` is not derived?

Is this general approach an acceptable idea, or is there a better alternative?

Comment: I don't see the need for a function that returns `T*`. Wouldn't it do to return `BaseType*`?

Comment: @juanchopanza because if I want to invoke functions on the derived class, I need a pointer to the derived class, in addition to what a container might do as it iterates through virtual base class functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to ensure that T is derived inside this function Factory?

If `functionThatAddsBaseClassPointerToContainer` takes a `Base*` it is already done.

```
Base* functionThatAddsBaseClassPointerToContainer(Base* b);  // <-- 

template<class T> //T is the derived class
static T* Factory(){
   // if T was not derived from Base, the following line fails to compile:
   return static_cast<T*>(functionThatAddsBaseClassPointerToContainer(new T));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure this at compile time using `std::is_base_of`. Assuming your base class is called `Base`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
static T* Factory()
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, 
                 "Error: template parameter T in Factory is not derived from Base");
    return static_cast<T*>(functionThatAddsBaseClassPointerToContainer(new T));
}
```

That being said, usually a factory function returns interface types, not derived types, so your design in this case is a bit odd.

Comment: It's not so odd if you need a container to store base class pointers using the `functionThatAdds` but you also need to store a pointer to the derived, returned by Factory, so you can independently use derived functions.